# CSS opacity on page load

Tags: html, css

I'm not great at making websites but am trying to make my own. Basically i split my page up in two, the left side being a menu bar and the right side containing content. To get a 'cool' blur effect over my menu bar i overlay it with a coloured image, where as the user hovers over it, the opacity changes (with a transition).

It is working as intended except when you click on a link and a new page loads, it doesn't register the hover until you move the mouse, this means the opacity of the image is full until you move even a tiny bit, then it jumps to 0.

Ideally when a new page opens and your mouse is already in the left region, the opacity of the overlaying image would already be 0.

```css
#left {
  text-indent: 1cm;
  width: 23%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
#right {
  padding-top: 2cm;
  width: 77%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}
#img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  color: #000;
  left: 0;
}
#left:hover>#img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I hope i have given enough information, thanks in advance

Bas

Answer (score 0):

How do you 'load' the page? is it ajax.load or? because if so, that language is already in use and therefor better to make a hover handler function in there because there is no way your CSS file is gonna notice on load wether the mouse is on your picture already or not untill you`ve moved it

Sorry i cant put comments down therefor i wrote here.

Comment: Clicking on a link opens a new page, it might be more clear if you look at my page. www.generowicz.nl

Comment: That is because when you click a page, then the page loads in the css and triggers the event. Every time you go to a new page, the page forget the previous one, and loads in the css called in the file wich causes this 'blinkin'.

Comment: In short, You click a page, it loads your css, it tells him how to behave.
But then when you click a new page, the same process is getting repeated.